# Get id after add new item by Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I need help with Entity Framework.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Prefix = "visit")] visit visit, [Bind(Prefix = "drugsEdition")]  IEnumerable<drugsEdition> drugsEdition, [Bind(Prefix = "accessoryEdition")]  IEnumerable<accessoryEdition> accessoryEdition, [Bind(Prefix = "servicesEdition")]  IEnumerable<servicesEdition> servicesEdition)
{
    Models.VisitDetails visitDetails = new Models.VisitDetails();
    visitDetails.visit = visit;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.visit.Add(visit);

        if (drugsEdition != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in drugsEdition)
            {
                item.idVisit = visit.id;
                db.drugsEdition.Add(item);
            }
        }

        if (accessoryEdition != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in accessoryEdition)
            {
                item.idVisit = visit.id;
                db.accessoryEdition.Add(item);
            }
        }

        if (servicesEdition != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in servicesEdition)
            {
                item.idVisit = visit.id;
                db.servicesEdition.Add(item);
            }
        }

        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = visit.id });
    }

    return View(visitDetails);
}
```

Model:

```
[Table("servicesEdition")]
public partial class servicesEdition
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    public int idService { get; set; }
    public int idVisit { get; set; }
    public double priceSell { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("idService")]
    public virtual services services { get; set; }
}
```

In this code, I added a new visit to the database, and I want get the visit's `id` after the code line `db.visit.Add (visit)`. When I add new `drugsEdition` and new `accessoryEdition`, this code is correct and added good `idVisit`, but when I added`servicesEdition` idVisit = 0. Why 'servicesEdition' doesn't get good idVisit ?

Comment: How does the `ServicesEdition` class definition looks like ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a `virtual` navigational property of type `Visit`, EF will get the corresponding visit id and fill that in when it saves a servicesEdition object on your `SaveChanges` method call.

I would also renaming the foreign key property to `VisitId` so that the referential integrity works by convention (naming convention) and you do not need to explicitly use the `ForeignKey` attribute. I would also recommend you to use PascalCasing when writing C# classes( not necessarily needed for your code to work)

```
public partial class ServicesEdition
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    public int idService { get; set; }

    public int VisitId { get; set; }

    public virtual Visit Visit { get; set; }

    public double priceSell { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("idService")]
    public virtual services services { get; set; }
}
```

If you do not want to alter the `ServicesEdition` entity definition like i described above, another option is to call the `SaveChanges()` method after you add the Visit entity and then you can access the Id property of that.

```
db.visit.Add(visit);
db.SaveChanges();

var visitId = db.Id;
//Now you can use visitId to save other entities
```

Comment: thanks, actually i have virtual Visit in another class 'accessoryEdition' and 'drugsEdition' But I did not know that there was a connection between entity.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `db.visit.Add(visit);` does not generate id until hit `db.SaveChanges();`

You could add `db.SaveChanges();` after `db.visit.Add(visit);`. 
Or you will save as a graph like Shyju explained.